# Github actions pull request builder returns error

Tags: github, github-actions, pull-request

I have a github actions job which is failing on the last job.
The build, unit test and regression test jobs are working fine but the pull-request job fails.

This is the code for the failing job, the token has been replaced.

```
  pull-request:
    needs: regression
    name: PullRequest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: pullrequest
      uses: repo-sync/pull-request@v2  
      with:
        source_branch: development                      
        destination_branch: master       
        pr_label: automerge        
        github_token: ${{ secrets.ghp_secretscretsecretetcetc }}
```

And this is the message I get when the job fails
[image]

[image]

Any ideas on what I am missing please?

Kev

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the problem is with the GITHUB_TOKEN you informed.

GitHub automatically creates a GITHUB_TOKEN secret to use in your workflow ([you can find more information about it here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/authentication-in-a-workflow)).

Therefore in your case, you can follow the specifications informed on the [action repository](https://github.com/repo-sync/pull-request) you're using:

```
pull-request:
    needs: regression
    name: PullRequest
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: pullrequest
      uses: repo-sync/pull-request@v2  
      with:
        source_branch: development                      
        destination_branch: master       
        pr_label: automerge        
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

If you ever need a GITHUB_TOKEN with specific permissions, you can also create a [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) and add it as a secret to your repository.

In that case, you would overwrite the `github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}` by `github_token: ${{ secrets.YOUR_SECRET_NAME }}`.